# Grouping, missing data - Cognos Report Studio

Tags: cognos-10, cognos-bi, cognos-8

In IBM Cognos Report Studio
I have a data structure like so, plain dump of the customer details:

```
Account|Type|Value
123-123| 19 |2000
123-123| 20 |2000
123-123| 21 |3000
```

If I remove the Type from my report I get:

```
Account|Value
123-123|2000
123-123|3000
```

It seems to have treated the two rows with an amount '2000' as some kind of duplicated amount and removed it from my report.

My assumption was that Cognos will aggregate the data automatically?

```
Account|Value
123-123|8000
```

I am lost on what it is doing. Any pointers? If it is not grouping it, I would at least expect 3 rows still

```
Account|Value
123-123|2000
123-123|2000
123-123|3000
```

In any case I would like to end up with 1 line. The behaviour I'm getting is something I can't figure out. Thanks for any help.

Gemmo

Answer (score 0):

The 'Auto-group & Summarize' feature is the default on new queries. This will find all unique combinations of attributes and roll up all measures to these unique combinations.

There are three ways to disable auto-group & summarize behavior:

1. Explicitly turn it off at the query level
2. Include a grain-level unique column, e.g. a key, in the query
3. Not include any measures in the query

My guess is that your problem is #3. The [Value] column in your example has to have its 'Aggregate Function' set to an aggregate function or 'Automatic' for the auto-group behavior to work. It's possible that column's 'Aggregate Function' property is set to 'None'. This is the standard setting for an attribute value and would prevent the roll up from occurring.